# How to make python machine learning libraries amenable to incremental learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, training-data

I need to frequently update my trained model using new training data without wanting to do the whole training again , so how to use some existing  libraries and ML algorithms to make it amenable to incremental learning? Ideally would like to see an example for NLTK bayes or scikit bayes. There are some answers here already which says it is difficult but I am sure there would be some libraries that would allow us to do :

model.update(new-trainingdata)

without repeating the same on entire data?

Answer (score 2):

In scikit-learn, you can make use of the `partial_fit()` function available in [MultinomialNB](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.partial_fit), [GaussianNB](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.partial_fit), and [BernoulliNB](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB.partial_fit) to incrementally fit your model to batches of data. This is useful when you're dealing with so much data that you can't fit it all in memory at once.

An example to show how this might work is as follows:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

X = np.array([[1],[0],[2],[3],[4],[5],[1],[2],[3],[1],[3]])
Y = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1])
all_classes = np.array([0,1])

clf = GaussianNB()

print clf.partial_fit(X, Y, classes=all_classes).class_count_

print clf.partial_fit(X,Y, classes=all_classes).class_count_
```

Yields

```
[ 4.  7.]
[  8.  14.]
```

Which makes sense since the classifier would have seen the 4 0's and 7 1's twice.

Comment: Thanks it shows error   raise TypeError('A sparse matrix was passed, but dense '
TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array.

Comment: How big is your data that you are using partial_fit on? If it's not too big, you might just try `X.toarray()` to turn the sparse matrix data structure into a dense numpy array.